# How can you check if all of a model's attributes have a value set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have the following method:

```
def complete?
  attributes.delete_if{|k,v| k == 'id' or k == 'user_id'}.values.each do |value|
    return false if value.blank?
  end
  true
end
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  I just want to know if, with my instance, all the attributes have been set apart from id and user_id. There must be a better way of doing this.

I'm on rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3 (just so people don't give answers that will work with newer versions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the [`validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) method to do that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :full_name, :username, :email, :address, presence: true
```

---

If you want to validate the presence of every attributes except few ones:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates *(self.column_names - ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']), presence: true
```

Above exemple extended:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates *self.validable_columns, presence: true

  def self.validable_columns
    excluded_columns = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'] # columns to be excluded in the `validates`
    self.column_names - excluded_columns 
  end
```

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot.  Because this is a has_one of another model (which is where I create it - after the parent's creation) I never even considered using validation to check if everything had been filled out.  This is on a completely seperate page to the above model in my application - just so you think I'm not nuts